# Como puedo solicitar una posicion Fila, columna para ser eliminadas de una matiz pidiendo un entero de siempre 2 valores?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa donde básicamente solicito la fila, columna de una matriz en un mismo dato *(una sola entrada)*,(**SIEMPRE SERAN DOS, ejemplo: 34)** . No logro crear la lógica para que el programa me valide que la posición a eliminar.

Ejemplo: al yo insertar el numero 24, fila 2 columna 4, no logro hacer que esa validación sea correcta para luego pasar a que el **if** me reconozca la condición.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
     /** MATRICES
            C0  C1  C2
        F0   1   2   3
        F1   4   5   6
        F2   7   8   9
    **/
    int A[][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    int filas=3,columnas=3;
    int B[filas][columnas];
    int fc;

    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            cout<<"["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] :";
            cin>>B[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            cout<<B[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"Insertar la fila-columna a eliminar :";
    cin>>fc;

    filas=fc/10;
    columnas=fc%10;

    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){

            if(B[i][j]==fc){

                B[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

     for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            cout<<B[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }



   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Recorres toda la matriz buscando el elemento que tiene el mismo valor que tecleas, 34, por ejemplo. ¿Eso es lo que pretendes? Porque ahí no pones a cero el elemento de la fila 3 columna 4, sino el elemento que tiene un 34 como contenido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No logro crear la lógica para que el programa me valide que la posición a eliminar.

Hay un par de conceptos que debes tener claro, el primero "*validar*" y el segundo "*eliminar*".

En cuanto a validar la entrada, ya nos ha quedado claro que tiene que ser un número entre `0` y `99` ya que como puede verse en tu código las filas serán las decenas y las columnas serán las unidades:

> ```
> filas=fc/10;
> columnas=fc%10;
> ```

Para validar que tus datos entran dentro del rango que exiges, tan sólo debes comprobarlo tras la lectura; lo más habitual en este tipo de programas es volver a pedir los datos si la entrada no coincide con lo esperado:

```
do
{
    cout << "Insertar la fila-columna a eliminar :";
    cin >> fc;
} while (!(fc >= 0 && fc < 100));
```

Recogiendo así los datos puedes asumir que una vez superado el bucle `do`-`while` la variable `fc` tendrá los datos correctos.

En cuanto a eliminar posiciones de una matriz, eso no es posible. Pero en tu código no parece que estés eliminando nada si no que asignas cero (`0`) al valor que coincide con la fila y columna solicitados:

> ```
> B[i][j]=0;
> ```

Teniendo eso en cuenta, es suficiente con esto:

```
B[fc / 10][fc % 10] = 0;
```

En resumen, tu código podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>
// No incluyas <cstdlib>, no la estás usando
// No incluyas <string>, no lo estás usando

// En C++ las funciones que no reciben parámetros se declaran con paréntesis
// vacíos, no con paréntesis con 'void'.
int main()
{
    // La cláusula using, mejor en main
    using namespace std;

    // No necesitas rellenar los datos para mostrar nada.
    int matriz[10][10];

    // Usa nombres autoexplicativos, favorece el ++preincremento antes que el postincremento++
    for (int fila = 0; fila != 10; ++fila) {
        for(int columna = 0; columna != 10; ++columna) {
            cout << '[' << fila << "][" << columna << "] :";
            cin >> matriz[fila][columna];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int fila = 0; fila != 10; ++fila) {
        for(int columna = 0; columna != 10; ++columna) {
            cout << matriz[fila][columna] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    // Declara las variables cerca de su punto de uso.
    int fc;
    do
    {
        cout << "Insertar la fila-columna a eliminar :";
        cin >> fc;
    } while (!(fc >= 0 && fc < 100));

    matriz[fc / 10][fc % 10] = 0;

    for (int fila = 0; fila != 10; ++fila) {
        for(int columna = 0; columna != 10; ++columna) {
            cout << matriz[fila][columna] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VO9btswEJ7Fp7i4aGxDSWwPWWrHS9uhQNGtk@HhTJ1SFhSp8sf9CfwwHjv0Kfxg7pGSmyItOhZBIEg83n13vO/jSbbtpdRobo/HZ8pIHSuChbI@OMJmKSYTeGchB76ih4X0odJqs7wAY0EjkA@HvYfo0VT2DzRXUea2B9sH4IR@beBlWXIhD3U0UllDHj5FSgmOpNqQgRbdYd9QcNaDJ6iI23VoQNou9t0E8sqncluUhx/W5/MehPN@uLWqGl4JZQI0qMxoLO5EwYlvEaQ@7KOPzCl6bvoCGvpoHXADCSmK7AWDDfkWJQELMRc5mSkbknxIYBqOtCaDjvl6qDDwl7tAaJKk7DZY4ZUoug5Ynm@r2XSd3r7Ye4/cfbNxLATGYOlLq5XEoLaJV41by7oQkIaybB2x1o4aMsECJqJZPA62fNx9rCxFUTOZUTq2VszxBqbzzjq7gRnbZZl2Y2A9EjQjpdWxMT34tPmF7x1dSiFtDLBYwHA1TEsuzetgvRqk9ZSdXfBiMM85ysByedIhpaxXPXCdADtxX5dMpdm3E/@NyV/byhRh@I/u@A5fdSOax3qLTuFG881IchJ5fMFHaGO6Mbajt/001JIL8G9R3P1Wd/DGeHIhjRNmkpen5vnX06pRadI6NXsxc5kdfP6gNMHobFRLWDJrOD/nECyY8XQ8TrN2oidhAmkE2XiejKzRo1fZUYjOpE5hdzzOxNN4rq/FTw)</kbd>:

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que te has enredado con eso de la matriz. Empecemos desde el punto que obtienes la fila y columna. Antes tienes que tener en cuenta que para el usuario las filas van del 1 la 10 y las columnas también del 1 al 10. Sin embargo, en nuestra matriz las filas y columnas van del 0 al 9.

NOTA: Existe el caso de seleccionar  cualquier columna de la fila 10. Para este caso lo resolveremos verificando el resultado de la división. Si es mayor a 100, entonces operamos sobre 100. No habrá ambigüedad en números de tres cifras dado que la matriz es cuadrada.Ignora la nota si tu matriz no llega a tener más de nueve filas y columna. Igual el algoritmo funciona.

```
    cout<<"Insertar la fila-columna a eliminar :";
    cin>>fc;


    int factor= ( (float) (fc/10.0))>=100.0 ? 100 : 10;

     filas=fc/factor;
     columnas=fc%factor;
     
    if(filas==0 || filas>10){
        // Error el usuario debe ingresar números mayores a 10  y menores a 1011
     }

     // Hacer lo mismo para columnas

    // Lo llevamos a las posiciones de la matriz
    --filas;
    --columnas;
     
    if(B[filas][columnas]==fc) // se supone que la matriz se llena con el número devfilacolumna
        B[filas][columnas]=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Según entendí tu consulta:
1)Quieres llenar una matriz dimensión máxima 10x10, para tu ejemplo creas una matriz 3x3.
2)Quieres ingresar por teclado un número de 2 dígitos, en el cual el primer dígito es la fila y el segundo dígito es la columna, luego mostrar matriz inicial en el cual se cambia por cero la fila y columna según el número de 2 dígitos ingresado.
Si esos son tus requisitos te comparto el código.

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
     /** MATRICES
            C0  C1  C2
        F0   1   2   3
        F1   4   5   6
        F2   7   8   9
    **/
   
    int filas=3,columnas=3;//aqui pones la dimensión de tu matriz en este caso es una matriz de 3x3
    int B[filas][columnas];
    int auxiliar[filas][columnas];//creamos una matriz auxiliar para copiar los valores luego de eliminar la fila-columna
    int fc;
    int filaEliminar,columnaEliminar;

    //LLenamos la matriz con valores por teclado
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            cout<<"["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] :";
            cin>>B[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    //Mostramos la matriz con los valores ingresados
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            cout<<B[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"Insertar la fila-columna a eliminar (convertir a 0) :";
    cin>>fc;

    filaEliminar=fc/10-1; //disminuimos en 1 porque nuestro recorrido comienza desde 0 hasta 2
    columnaEliminar=fc%10-1; //disminuimos en 1 porque nuestro recorrido comienza desde 0 hasta 2 
    
    /**copiamos los valores de nuestra matriz en una matriz auxiliar, en fila y columna a eliminar
       cambiamos el valor por 0 **/
     for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            if(i==filaEliminar&&j==columnaEliminar)
                auxiliar[i][j]=0;            
            else auxiliar[i][j]=B[i][j];            
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
    //Mostramos nuestra nueva matriz
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){ 
            cout<<auxiliar[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
   return 0;
 }
```